# How to give preference to a my stylesheet over bootstrap in REACT(which is included in index.js file)?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to override some properties of bootstrap by defining my own stylesheet and then importing it in my xyz.js file(for some component) like this:

**Xyz.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import qs from 'qs';
import '../css/company.css'
export default class Xyz extends Component{ 
    constructor(props){
        .....
    }
    render(){       
        return( 
            <div className="container" style={{float: "left"}}>

                <table className = "table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{this.props.index + 1}</td>
                            <td>{this.props.company.name}</td>
                            <td>{this.props.company.type}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

// I am trying to set border-top of <td> to 0px which is set to 1px 
//by default by bootstrap.css but I am not able to do so
```

**xyz.css**

```
td {
    border-top-width: 0px;
    height: 2px;
}
```

I am trying to set `border-top` of 'td' tag to `0px` which is set to `1px` 
        by default by `bootstrap.css` but I am not able to do so.

Comment: Use stronger selector: `.container .table td {...}`. Or use `!important`. And optimal variant: don't use bootstrap at all if you want your own design

Answer (score 0):

CSS chooses which rule to use when there are multiple rules available based on a few different criteria which you should definitely Google and read more about. But in this case two things can help:

1. Specifity: again I hope you research this more on yourself. But basically adding a class to your td and styling td.classname will increase the specifity of your rule and make it override the less specific type selector provided by Bootstrap
2. !important: you can put !important after your rule to make sure it overrides everything. However there are also a lot of really cool criteria based on which multiple !important rules get ordered and applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can use important for your styles.

Another option is to use [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/). In which you can make your own styles for different tables as below.

```
import { styled } from 'styled-components';

const UserTD = styled.td`
  border-top-width: 0px;
  height: 2px;
`

<UserTD>{this.props.index + 1}</UserTD>
```